# Is it possible to have a dynamic curl output in a for loop using bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to do a for loop who will takes all incident in each pages using bash and curl.

i declared an array and trying to put all data in it but i do just have the first pages datas.

Could you please help me to find a solution :-/

```
for (( i=1; i<=3; i++))
do
field["$i"]=$(curl -H "X-test-Authorization: Bearer eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM2NDAyLCJnZW5lcmF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDE4LTA2LTI1IDA5OjA3OjAzIn0"
  -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' -X GET https://api.test.com/incidents.xml?layout=long&page="$i")
done

echo "${field[*]}" >>  ~/Desktop/AllIncidents2.csv
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing is dumping array into a file then you can just do this way:

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
   curl -H 'X-test-Authorization: Bearer eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM2NDAyLCJnZW5lcmF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDE4LTA2LTI1IDA5OjA3OjAzIn0' \
  -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' -X GET 'https://api.test.com/incidents.xml?layout=long&page='"$i"
done >> ~/Desktop/AllIncidents2.csv
```

Comment: I tried like this too but do have the same behaviour. I just have the first page's data in the file

Comment: Remove `>> ~/Desktop/AllIncidents2.csv` from above and check output of your script first by doing: `bash script.sh | cat -A`

Comment: Now i do have this error message : curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16304)

Comment: Try with additional quotes I added in answer. Though I think you have some other `curl` issue.

Comment: Seams that loaded data aren't correct, will check to fix that thanks